# "injectionPointRegexp" is not a supported parameter when using workbox wizard

Tags: workbox

I am using workbox wizard to create the workbox-config.js as the documentation states:

https://github.com/mikegeyser/workbox-wizardry/blob/master/overview.md#level-2-template-service-worker

My config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "public/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{ico,html,png,json,txt}"
  ],
  "swDest": "public/sw.js",
  "swSrc": "src/sw.js",
  "injectionPointRegexp": /(const precacheManifest = )\[\](;)/
}
```

I get following error when trying to inject the manifest:

```
 ✘ alxxo@Axxxx  ~/Documents/coda/pwa-xx   workbox ●✚  workbox injectManifest workbox-config.js
Using configuration from /xxxxx/workbox-config.js.

Your configuration is invalid:
{
  "globDirectory": "public/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{ico,html,png,json,txt}"
  ],
  "swDest": "public/sw.js",
  "swSrc": "src/sw.js",
  "injectionPointRegexp" [1]: {}
}

[1] "injectionPointRegexp" is not a supported parameter.
```

How can it be not a supported parameter if it appears in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the latest version of Workbox.

If you're using Workbox v5 or higher, then the correct parameter name is [`injectionPoint`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.injectManifest). Instead of a RegExp, you now pass in a string if you need to override the default.

The [default behavior in v5](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4#default_precache_manifest_replacement_point) is to look for the symbol `self.__WB_MANIFEST` somewhere in your `swSrc` file, and replace that with the precache manifest.

Comment: in the documentation they tell you to use an empty array: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/workbox-build, if you use the workbox-build, the self.__WB_MANIFEST is to be used when using  workbox CLI. I guess documentation is weather wrong or unclear